# Get missed calls, sms and mails in Android

Tags: android, email, sms

I would like to know how can I retrieve missed calls, sms and emails.

Assuming we got 3 textviews for each example:

```
private TextView mMissedCallsCount;
private TextView mLastMissedCallContactName;
private TextView mLastMissedCallContactNumber;

private TextView mUnreadedSMSCount;
private TextView mLastUnreadedSMSContactName; //or number
private TextView mLastUnreadedSMSContent;

private TextView mUnreadedEmailsCount;
private TextView mLastUnreadedEmailFrom; //contact
private TextView mLastUnreadedEmailContent;
```

Someone would be so kind as to show a simple method to obtain the desired content?

Comment: there is no contentprovider for emails. as for calls and sms, plenty of tutorials can be found by a simple search.

Comment: as i said in my questions, many of the answers i red here are unworking or really hardcoded. Maybe you can be so kind to point me to a working solution? Thank you

Comment: What is a "missed SMS"? What is a "missed email"?

Comment: unreaded SMS and unreaded Emails.. sorry for my bad english!